# How do i group a certain number of elements with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I need some quick help on selecting items with jQuery. It might be a very simple solution, but... I can't see one right one besides cloning and duplicating elements.
So, here we go. I have this kind of structure on a page:

http://content.screencast.com/users/iamntz/folders/Jing/media/2fa05c60-f4fc-4178-b9b6-187831e1ca31/2010-11-22_1741.png

I want to group each six elements into a wrapper element, in order to have `.quotesWrapper > (.sixQuoteWrapper > .quote * 6) * 4`.

Any idea how i could achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure i could get this without an each if i gave it a few more mins, but this works.

Here is a [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/64c9z/)

```
$('.quotesWrapper .quote.split').each(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil('.quote.split')
        .andSelf()
        .wrapAll('<div class="wrap" />')
});
```

Answer (score 2):

@John Hartsock's solution is concise but inefficient because of the number of times the selectors are run.  I would suggest a variation on his:

```
var i = 0, 
    quotes = $("div.quoteWrapper").children(),
    group;

while ((group = quotes.slice(i, i += 6)).length) {
    group.wrapAll('<div class="sixQuoteWrapper"></div>');
}
```

This solution runs a shorter selector just once and retrieves the children, making it faster.

**Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/FFf6z/**

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want. Essentially you loop through untill you have no more div.quote items under div.quoteWrapper. This is using the [:lt() selector](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)

```
while ($("div.quoteWrapper > div.quote").length) {
  $("div.quoteWrapper > div.quote:lt(6)").wrapAll('<div class="sixQuoteWrapper"></div>');
}
```

Comment: `.wrapAll()` is what's needed, `wrap()` wraps each element individually.