# Sort and separate a set of list elements using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I have a question
Sort the list (you can use default JS/jquery sorting functions )
Break the sorted list apart into different sub-lists with a maximum of 'x' items each,  'x' being a parameter you pass in. The above
sample result assumes x=2

```
<ul>
   <li> 4 </li>
   <li> 1 </li>
   <li> 7 </li>
   <li> 5 </li>
   <li> 3 </li>
 </ul>
```

Write a function to convert that to

```
<ul>
    <li> 1 </li>
    <li> 3 </li>
</ul>
 <ul>
    <li> 4 </li>
    <li> 5 </li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li> 7 </li>
</ul>
```

Feel free to use any libraries/references you like within reason (i.e., don't use a library which has a "splitList" function). The key is to do this as efficiently as possible in terms of DOM manipulation.

i solved this question by creating separate list and deleted the original but I am wondering how can we do it by only modifying the existing one.(I mean modify on the fly while traversing)

Answer (score 1):

html first:

```
<ul id="list">
   <li> 4 </li>
   <li> 1 </li>
   <li> 7 </li>
   <li> 5 </li>
   <li> 3 </li>
</ul>
<div id="container"></div>
```

javascript(jquery):

```
function sortText(a,b){  
    return $(a).text().trim() > $(b).text().trim() ? 1 : -1;  
};
var ul = $('#list');
var elements = ul.find('li').detach();
var i=2;
var lastul;
var container = $('#container');
elements.sort(sortText).each(function(index){
    if (index % i === 0) {
        container.append(lastul);
        lastul = $('<ul></ul>');
    }
    lastul.append(elements[index]);
})
container.append(lastul);
ul.remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var optionTexts = [];
        $("ul li").each(function() { optionTexts.push($(this).text()) });
        optionTexts.sort();
        //alert(optionTexts.length);
        var splityby = 2;//change this value how you want to split
        var itmes= parseInt(optionTexts.length/splityby);
        var remaining = optionTexts.length%splityby;
        //alert(itmes+'and'+remaining);
        var st='';
        var i=0;
        for(k=0;k<itmes+remaining;k++){
            st+='<ul>';
            for(j=0;j<splityby;j++){
                if(i<optionTexts.length){
                st+='<li>'+optionTexts[i++] +'</li>' ;
                }
            } 
            st+='</ul>';
        }
        $('#hi').append(st);
```

---

html

```
    <div id="hi"></div> 
<ul>    <li> 4 </li>    <li> 1 </li>    <li> 7 </li>    <li> 5 </li>    <li> 3 </li>  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient method to sort is by using the native `Array.sort` method (`jQuery().sort` implements the `Array.sort`). **Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RJEJQ/1/**.

The code can become even more efficient by getting rid of jQuery, and using `document.createElement()` and ordinary `for()` loops.

```
var originalUl = $('ul');
var listElements = originalUl.children('li'); //List
listElements.sort(function(x, y){
    return parseInt(x.textContent, 10) - parseInt(y.textContent);
});
//Sorted by number, 1, 2, 3, ...

var newList = $(""); //Placeholder
listElements.each(function(i){
    if(i%2 == 0){ //If even, a new list has to be created
        originalUl.before(newList);
        newList = $("<ul>"); //Create new list

    }
    newList.append(this);
});
if(newList.length) { // If there are any remaining list elements in the holder.
    originalUl.before(newList);
}
originalUl.remove(); //Remove original, empty ul.
```

As seen at **[this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RJEJQ/1/)**, the result looks like:

```
ul
    li 1
    li 3
ul
    li 4
    li 5
ul
    li 7
```

Comment: Note: Change `i%2` by `i%3` if you want to display three list items per `<ul>`.

Answer (score 1):

This partially uses an answer I wrote before that [divides elements into groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247188/how-do-i-group-a-certain-number-of-elements-with-jquery/4247400#4247400), with the addition of sorting them first:

```
Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/QVRRn/
```

```
var i   = 0,
    ul  = $("ul"), 
    lis = ul.children().detach(),
    group;

// Sort the elements
lis.sort(function (a, b) {
    return $.text(a).localeCompare($.text(b));
});

// Wrap the elements
while ((group = lis.slice(i, i += 2)).length)
    group.wrapAll('<ul></ul>');

// Replace the original UL element
ul.replaceWith(lis.closest("ul"));
```

It's important to detach the `<li>` elements from the document before manipulating them, this will make the operation much faster on large sets.

Answer (score 0):

If you must have to manipulate DOM, I believe your question was answered.
But...

[DOM manipulation](http://brianegan.com/jquery-dom-manipulation-und-performance/) is [slow](http://www.tvidesign.co.uk/blog/improve-your-jquery-25-excellent-tips.aspx#tip6). 
[Concatenate strings also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112158/javascript-string-concatenation).

The sort function was taken from here: [How may I sort a list alphabetically using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134976/how-may-i-sort-a-list-alphabetically-using-jquery)

Live demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/gknjQ/1/